# Angular 2 attribute directive input values are undefined and not set correctly

Tags: angular, directive

I have following directive (TextElementDirective), that has 4 input variables colorHex, fontFamily, fontWeight, fontStyle. I want to set an element's color and style using this directive.

```ts
@Directive(
{
    selector: "[text-element-map]",
    // host: {
    //     '(mousemove)': "onMouseMove()"
    // }
}
)

export class TextElementDirective{
@Input() colorHex : string;
@Input() fontFamily : string;
@Input() fontWeight : string;
@Input() fontStyle : string;

constructor(private el: ElementRef){
    this.setElement();
}

setElement(){
    if(this.colorHex){
        this.el.nativeElement.style.color = this.colorHex;
    }
    if(this.fontFamily){
        this.el.nativeElement.style.fontFamily = this.fontFamily;
    }
    if(this.fontWeight){
        this.el.nativeElement.style.fontWeight = this.fontWeight;
    }
    if(this.fontStyle){
        this.el.nativeElement.style.fontStyle = this.fontStyle || "";
    }
}

onMouseMove(){
    this.setElement();
}
}
```

When I use this directive in another component, as an attribute, it doesn't set the element style and color. Even if you click the button, the element values are not set.

If I use a host (onmousemove) in the directive, it works fine. But I want to set the values during start up.

Any idea what am i missing?

Here is the test component that uses it.

```ts
@Component({
template:
`
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <div>
        <span>text-element-map: </span>
        <span class="text-content" text-element-map [colorHex]="colorHex" 
             [fontFamily]="fontFamily" [fontWeight]="fontWeight" [fontStyle]="fontStyle">Change this text</span>

        <button (click)="setCurrentDesignElement()">Click</button>
    </div>
`,
directives:[TextElementDirective],
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class TestComponent{

@ViewChild(TextElementDirective)
private childTextElement: TextElementDirective;


colorHex: string = "#e2e2e2";
fontFamily: string = "Arial";
fontWeight: string = "normal";
fontStyle: string = "normal";

setCurrentDesignElement(){
    this.color = {
        hex: "#B4B4B4",
        id: 5745,
        name: "Athletic Heather"
    };

    this.font = {
        cssString: "Valera Round",
        weight: "normal",
        style: "italic"
        };

    this.colorHex = "#B4B4B4";
    this.fontFamily = "Valera Round";
    this.fontWeight = "normal";
    this.fontStyle = "italic";    

    //this.childTextElement.setElement();
}


}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`Input()`s aren't available in the constructor. They are set by change detection, and change detection is run after the component is instantiated. The lifecycle hooks `ngOnChanges` (every update) and `ngOnInit` (once after the first `ngOnChanges` call) are called after change detection updated an input:

Change

```ts
constructor(private el: ElementRef){
    this.setElement();
}
```

to

```ts
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {};

ngOnInit() {
  this.setElement();
}
```

`ngOnInit()` is called after the inputs are initialized.

---

Instead of

```ts
this.el.nativeElement.style.color = this.colorHex;
```

it's better to use

```ts
@HostBinding('style.color')
@Input() colorHex : string;

@HostBinding('style.font-family')
@Input() fontFamily : string;

@HostBinding('style.font-weight')
@Input() fontWeight : string;

@HostBinding('style.font-style')
@Input() fontStyle : string;
```

Actually I haven't tried myself to add `@HostBinding()` and `@Input()` on the same field, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: It works when the directive is initialized. But when I click the button to reset colorHex, fontFamily, etc.. it doesn't reset the text. How do I make sure that the setElement () is called when the model changes? Why is the change detection not taking over?

Comment: There are two ways: make `colorHex`, ... setters and getters or change `ngOnInit()` to `ngOnChanges(changes)`. `ngOnChanges` is called every time input values change. With my suggestion above you shouldn't need `setElement()` at all.

Comment: Yes. You are right. When I use HostBinding, I don't need setElement function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Doh!  So obvious now.  Thankyou.

Comment: Shouldn't the ctor be changed to 'constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}'?

Comment: @Drammy thanks - fixed (mixed in a bit of Dart syntax ;-) )